# How to call .NET web service from ajax?

Tags: ajax, web-services, same-origin-policy, cross-domain-proxy

How to call .NET web service from ajax call? I am facing same origin policy error. How can I resolve that?

Comment: What service? Web API, WCF, ASMX?

Comment: It is asmx web service @Shuping. I have tried
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); in php but the issue didn't resolve.

Comment: The COR header should be put in the target service which is your ASMX service instead of in PHP

Comment: @Shuping No, COR headers are sent by the server, and must be issued from server side using something like PHP http://enable-cors.org/server_php.html

Comment: @Oscar "sent by the server" is exactly what i am saying. Check the question: the server side (of the Web Service) is ASMX which is .NET, that's why I am saying the ASMX service (which is for sure the server side of the API) should attach the COR headers. And from Gaur's comment, the PHP code if for building the AJAX pages, is actually "client side" to the ASMX.

Answer (score -1):

Your web service should allow you to request on It.

For example in php

```
 <?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Where "*" could be replaced by your server location

In dot net, it could be something like (I don't know .NET)

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://mywebclient.azurewebsites.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```